# HashMap with input of Predicate type in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am working on a pre-existing java program, one of its classes calculates some Boolean features. It uses `HashMap` for implementing this, so that the first argument is a `String` type and the second one is a `Predicate` type:

```
featureMap = new HashMap<String, Predicate<ChunkedBinaryExtraction>>
```

The featureMap is set manually by some strings and Predicate values which are defined and returned by some private methods (for example: `featureMap.put("extr phrase", extrCoversPhrase());` ).

I need to access the features’ values (second Arguments), so I used this code:

```
 Set set = featureMap.entrySet();
 Iterator i = set.iterator();
 while(i.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
    System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
    System.out.println(me.getValue());   
 }
```

It could extract first argument properly but not the second one (features’ values)! It returns something like this:

```
extr phrase: edu.washington.cs.knowitall.extractor.conf.ReVerbFeatures$11@36aa7bc2
```

It seems that `me.getValue()` isnot a proper statement for retrieving features' values?

Comment: Parametrize your `Set` and `Map.entry` appropriately instead of using raw types.

Comment: @Mena is right ! Don't use raw types ! Check Effective Java 2nd Edition, Chapter 5, Item 23 : don't use raw types !

Answer (score 1):

That print out simply tells you that the map value is an object of class ReVerbFeatures. And that class didn't override the "toString()" method, thus giving you some not-so-human-readable output.

But the thing is: you do have an object of that class at hand. So you could be casting it

```
ReVerbFeatures feature = (ReVerbFeatures) me.getValue();
```

to then call any of the methods of that class, for example.

And as others have said: read about "raw types", and if possible, change that code accordingly.

Finally: if you have to deal with code ... then there is no way but learning about all the involved concepts. You shouldn't be dealing with stuff that you don't understand. Meaning: you should decide, if you have the time to really learn about all these things; or stop doing what you are doing right now. Avoid being responsible for something ... if you lack the skills to be really in charge.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I applied your solution but it  shows this: edu.washington.cs.knowitall.extractor.conf.ReVerbFeatures$13 cannot be cast to edu.washington.cs.knowitall.extractor.conf.ReVerbFeatures

Comment: Ah, right. The $ number indicates some inner class. So maybe you have to rework your question ... to tell us what you actually want to do with those values.

Comment: :(Isn't there any way to retrieve those features? for a given sentence, it considers some features and calculates them as boolean features(true or false). each private method sets a value of one of the features, I need a vector of these features (for example (0, 1, 0,..)).